# Why is Kernel of $S\otimes_R S \to S$ an ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules

I'm reading article about Kähler differentials in Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential#Definition_using_the_augmentation_ideal

The article said:

Another construction proceeds by letting $I$ be the **ideal** in the tensor product $S\otimes_R S$ defined as the kernel of the multiplication map:

$$S\otimes_R S \to S$$
$$\sum s_i\otimes t_i\mapsto \sum s_i\cdot t_i$$

Why the Kernel $I$ is an ideal of $S$? (I suppose that the map is an $S$-homomorphism).

Comment: It's an ideal of $S \otimes_R S$, not of $S$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry again, but I have a doubt again. If I is a ideal of the ring $S\otimes_R S$ (or a R-algebra), then $I$ and $I/I^2$ are $(S\otimes_R S)$-submodules. However, according to definition of $\Omega_{S/R}$, should not $I/I^2$ be a $S$-Module?. Is $s·(s_1\otimes s_2)=(s·s_1)\otimes s_2$

Comment: If $B=A/I$ and $M$ is an $A$-module such that $IM=0$, then $M$ is a $B$-module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile the answers in the comments:

> Why is $\ker(S\otimes_R S\to S)$ an ideal of $S$?

It isn't, it's an ideal of $S\otimes_R S.$ In general, the kernel of any ring homomorphism $A\to B$ is always an ideal of $A.$

> If $I$ is a ideal of the ring $S\otimes_R S$ (or a $R$-algebra), then $I$ and $I/I^2$ are $S\otimes_R S$-submodules. However, according to definition of $\Omega_{S/R}$, should not $I/I^2$ be a $S$-Module?

As A.G says, if $B = A/I$ and $M$ is an $A$-module such that $IM = 0,$ then $M$ becomes a $B$-module. Let $b = a + I\in B,$ and let $m\in M.$ Then we may define $b\cdot m = a\cdot m,$ and this is well-defined because if $a + I = a' + I,$ then we have $a - a'\in I,$ so that $(a - a')\cdot m = 0$ for any $m\in M.$